# Can we extract data types of features/variables from pickled model for Logistic Regression, Decision Tree, Random Forest?

Tags: machine-learning-model, data-science-model, pickle

I am trying to extract data types of variables/features from a pickled ML model file. I could see there is no information of the data types of variables in pickle file except for XG Boost. Is there any way to extract the data type information from pickle model file for other ML algorithms?

Comment: Most types of model use only numerical values, so in most cases anyway it would be impossible to know if the original features before representation were categorical (in particular strings).

Comment: Thanks for the information @Erwan